# Accessing data in an object array with Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, cucumber

I'm currently working with Cucumber and Java. I would like to retrieve that path of a file from `ITestResult`.

I'm currently retrieving the parameters with:

```
Object[] test = testResult.getParameters();
```

However the only thing I can access would seem the be the first objects name and nothing else.

```
test = {Object[1]@1492} 
    0 = {CucumberFeatureWrapper@1493} "Links at EDM Documents View,"
        cucumberFeature = {CucumberFeature@1516} 
            path = "test/01-automation.feature"
            feature = {Feature@1518} 
            cucumberBackground = null
            currentStepContainer = {CucumberScenario@1519} 
            cucumberTagStatements = {ArrayList@1520}  size = 1
            i18n = {I18n@1521} 
            currentScenarioOutline = null
```

I cannot see anyway of retrieving `path = "test/01-automation.feature"` under cucumber feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like `((CucumberFeatureWrapper)test[0]).getCucumberFeature().getPath()`?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, there is nothing cucumber related under test[0].

Comment: I've edited my answer. The `Object` array's first element is a `CucumberFeatureWrapper` object which contains the path you need.

Comment: That works! Fantastic! Thank you! I did not see that at all.